# Error System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectedValue.get devolvio null en combobox WPF

Tags: visual-studio, wpf, xaml, c#-8.0

primero doy gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda que llegue y pido perdon si me voy por las ramas, es primera vez que pido ayuda en la plataforma :(

Me encuentro en un problemita respecto a una parte de un codigo que realizo para mi portafolio de titulo. Ocurre que mi codigo en cierta parte requiere de seleccionar un pais, region y ciudad para asignarsela a un usuario, teniendo estos dentro de 3 combobox que relleno mediante procedimientos almacenados desde oracle.

Codigo .xaml donde realizo la creacion de mis combobox

```
            <ComboBox x:Name="cbPais" Margin="595,65,106,0" Loaded="CbPais_Loaded" SelectionChanged="CbPais_SelectionChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Label x:Name="EstadoLabel" Content="Region" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="468,126,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cbEstado" Margin="595,121,106,0" SelectionChanged="CbEstado_SelectionChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Label x:Name="CiudadLabel" Content="Ciudad" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="468,184,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cbCiudad" Margin="595,184,106,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Codigo .cs de la carga de datos

```
private void cargarPais()
        {
            cbPais.SelectedValue = 0;
            try
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM PAIS ORDER BY N_PAIS", conn);
                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                DataRow fila = dt.NewRow();

                cbPais.SelectedValuePath = "ID_PAIS";
                cbPais.DisplayMemberPath = "N_PAIS";
                cbPais.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al leer pais");
            }
        }
        private void cargarRegion(string id_pais)
        {
            cbEstado.SelectedValue = 0;
            try
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM estados WHERE pais_id_pais = :id_pais", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(":id_pais", id_pais);
                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                DataRow fila = dt.NewRow();

                cbEstado.SelectedValuePath = "ID_ESTADO";
                cbEstado.DisplayMemberPath = "N_ESTADO";
                cbEstado.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
        private void cargarCiudad(string id_estado)
        {
            cbCiudad.SelectedValue = 0;
            try
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM ciudad WHERE estados_id_estado = :id_estado", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(":id_estado", id_estado);
                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                DataRow fila = dt.NewRow();

                cbCiudad.SelectedValuePath = "ID_CIUDAD";
                cbCiudad.DisplayMemberPath = "N_CIUDAD";
                cbCiudad.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

Los primeros combobox que cargan pais y region se ocupan principalmente para darme una ciudad, teniendo fallos en una interaccion en especifico a la hora de utilizar el .selectionChanged de region, donde falla a la hora de cambiar el pais teniendo una region seleccionada.

parte del .cs que me complica:

```
 private void CbPais_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cbPais.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)
            {
                string id_pais = cbPais.SelectedValue.ToString();
                cargarRegion(id_pais);
            }
        }
        private void CbEstado_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cbEstado.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)
            {
                string id_estado = cbEstado.SelectedValue.ToString();
                cargarCiudad(id_estado);
            }
        }
```

Donde me da el siguiente error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Enserio que aprecio cualquier ayuda ya que es lo unico que me falla en mi codigo :(

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que los `combobox` tienen un `index -1`, y que al cargarse disparan el `SelectionChanged`  (tenga elementos o no), por tanto, si el combo está vacío, igualmente cargará el `index -1` y si no hay nada allí lógicamente su contenido será `null`, yo verificaría si el `SelectedIndex` es mayor a -1 y entonces comprobaría si el `SelectedValue` es distinto de `NULL`.

Puedes hacer las 2 comprobaciones en el mismo if para ahorrarte una línea, lo del index es así:

```
if(cbEstado.SelectedIndex > -1)
```

Lo mismo para el Combobox de países, como siempre hay países seguramente no tienes ese problema, pero puede ocurrir que falle la carga y el Combobox quede vacío, entonces tendrías ese problema también.

```
if(cbPaís.SelectedIndex > -1)
```

Suerte.